# Is there a way to tell through reflection, the difference between an auto property and a regular one?

Tags: c#, reflection

So an auto property is one which is declared like this:

```
int autoProp {get; private set;}
```

Where the associated member variable is automatically generated.

In the property list returned by `GetType().GetProperties()`, is there a way to distinguish between the two properties in the following class:

```
class MyClass
{
    int regularPropertyValue;
    int regularProperty 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return regularPropertyValue;
        } 
        set 
        {
            regularPropertyValue = value;
        } 
    }
    int autoProperty {get; private set;}    
};
```

Comment: As you wrote, the associated member variable is generated automatically. This means, the resulting code, which is read by reflection is the same.

Comment: The compiler creates fields for each auto property named `<PropertyName>k__BackingField`, but it's supposed to be an "under the hood" thing you shouldn't depend on. They are listed if you call `GetFields()` with the correct `BindingFlags`.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to access the <PropertyName>k__BackingField fields in a way that is safe and cross platform? This is for the purpose of serialisation.

Comment: No it's never safe to assume compilers don't change their internal workings. Is there a reason you can't use the property itself? Perhaps there is a more elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: The reason I don't want to use the property itself is because I might end up serialising certain private members twice, as I will be serialising all private members and all public properties, that might access a private member.

Comment: As far as I know, `BinaryFormatter` serializes all fields (including the ones generated for auto properties). Because it completely ignores properties, it doesn't need to "map" fields to properties at all. You're probably going to end up chosing between serializing all fields, or serializing public properties by default, with an option to override using attributes like `XmlSerializer` does.